# How to declare global variable for all users Temporarily using bash?

Tags: bash

I want to run a process in background using disown and store its `PID` inside a global variable then when ever I want to close it I use `PID` inside it to kill the process but how can I declare a variable like so?

Infact I want to use the `PID` even if I close terminal that starts the process that's why I want to store the `pid`.

Comment: I searched but sadly I couldn't find any thing. I don't think so but anyway sorry if my search was poorly and thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "global variable" - processes simply inherit environment values from their parent. You could consider storing the PID in a file instead.

Comment: Write the PID of the process into a file in `/tmp/` that everybody can read , e.g. `echo $$ >/tmp/my.pid && chmod 644 /tmp/my.pid`.

Comment: ... or perhaps in /run or /var/run as per `man hier`: *"Run-time  variable  files,  like  files  holding process identifiers (PIDs)"*

Comment: What would other users do with the PID of your process? Add this info to the question, not as comment !